# pass custom variable for image field from preprocess node to twig

Tags: 8, theming

I have a content type (`gallery`) with an image field which is unlimited: `field_picture`.
I have a logic which calculates custom css classes to their HTML containers, like: `grid-item--width1`, `grid-item--width2`, `grid-item--height1`, `grid-item--height2`.
I store these in the `grid_class`.
I can't merge these classes with the item class, because I want to style different HTML containers by them.

I tried to add this new variable (grid_class) to the image elements from the `mytheme_preprocess_node__gallery` and I thought drupal8 will pass them to the twig template.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node__gallery(&$variables)
{
  foreach (Element::children($variables['elements']['field_picture']) as $key) {
    // here is my logic which calculates the classes for the image elements' containers
    $grid_class = "grid-item--width1 grid-item--height1";
    $variables['elements']['field_picture'][ $key ]['grid_class'] = $grid_class;
  }
}
```

but in my twig template (`themes/custom/mytheme/templates/field/field--node--field-picture--gallery.html.twig`) when I loop through the `items`, the `grid_class` isn't available.

```
{% for key, item in items %}

    {{ (dump(item)) }}

    <div{{ item.attributes }}>
      <div class="grid-item {{ item.grid_class }}">{{ item.content }}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I also tried to add it from `mytheme_preprocess_field()`. I saw the array of the `field_picture` element, but I didn't find the items in there.

any help or hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I have to use the `mytheme_preprocess_field` hook.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['field_name'] == "field_picture") {
    foreach ($variables['items'] as $key => $item) {
      $grid_class = "grid-item--width1 grid-item--height1";
      $variables['items'][ $key ]['grid_class'] = $grid_class;
    }
  }
}
```